# Solution of a homogenous system of linear equations is a linear subspace - formulation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

Let $Ax=b$, $A\in \mathbb{F}^{n\times m}$ be a system of linear equations. Show that its set of solution is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff it is a homogeneous system.

$\to$ If $b=0$ then the system has at least one solution which is a trivial one or, moreover, infinite number of solutions (including the trivial one). Clearly, in both cases the solutions set is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (it includes the null space and closed under additivity and scalar multiplication).

Alternatively,
If $b\neq0$ then has no solution or has a unique solution, both way is a vector of constant terms which don't satisfies the condition of a linear subspace.

Is the logic OK? How to prove the opposite way and finally formalize it compactly and friendly without too many mess?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer contains quite a few leaps of logic I'm afraid. Let's go over your arguments in detail.

> $\rightarrow$ If $b=0$ then the system has at least one solution
>   which is a trivial one

This is correct.

> or, moreover, infinite number of solutions (including the trivial one).

While this is true for infinite fields, it is not true for a finite field.
And what's worse is that you are just asserting this without any proof. You'll have to give an argument for why this is the case.

> Clearly, in both cases the solutions set is a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n$

True (and obvious) if $0$ is the only solution. But there are plenty of infinite subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ that are not subspaces.

> (it includes the null space and closed under additivity and scalar multiplication).

This is the part you actually need to show.

> Alternatively,
>   If $b\neq 0$ then has no solution or has a unique solution, both way is a vector of constant terms which don't satisfies the condition of a linear subspace.

In general there might be a lot of solutions of $Ax=b$ even if $b\neq 0$. For example, if $A=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $b=1$ then all vectors whose first component is $1$ are solutions. In general the solutions of such an equation form a so called affine subspace.

So how do we prove it? Let us call the set of solutions $S$. We want to show that $S$ is a linear subspace if and only if $b=0$.

$\Rightarrow$: Let us assume that $S$ is a linear subspace. Then $0\in S$ which means that $A0=b$. Therefore $0=A0=b$.

$\Leftarrow$: Suppose $b=0$ we want to show that $S$ is a linear subspace. So we need to show that $S$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. For addition assume that $x,y\in S$. This means that $Ax=0$ and $Ay=0$. Therefore $A(x+y) = Ax +Ay=0+0=0$, which means that $x+y\in S$.

I'll leave it up to you to show that $S$ is also closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: It is usually part of the definition of subspace that $0$ is included. The alternative is to demand that a subspace $V$ is nonempty. But then if $x\in V$ we must also have $0=0\cdot x\in V$ because $0$ is a scalar and $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication.